# Efficiently Query and Save Most Recent Date of Boolean Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, subquery

I have a table saving dates things were done by a boolean value after a date.  I need to query this to run a report that tells me the date each of the most recent columns was done.  So the table looks like this:

```
id item date        sweep dust vacuum wash
1   1   2021-01-01    t
2   1   2021-02-02          t      
3   1   2021-03-03    t          t 
4   1   2021-04-04                     t
5   1   2021-05-05    t     t
6   1   2021-06-06               t
```

The report needs to be like:

```
TASK     MOST RECENT
sweep    2021-05-05
dust     2021-05-05
vacuum   2021-06-06
wash     2021-04-04
```

I'd like to figure out the most efficient way to query for this so I can display the dates in a datatable as I have up to potentially 100,000 items in the database I'll be tracking.

Note: It's possible I can change how the date/task data is stored if needed for efficiency of reporting.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
(
  select 'sweep' as task, date from t 
  where sweep = 't' order by date desc limit 1
) union all (
  select 'dust', date from t 
  where dust = 't' order by date desc limit 1
) union all (
  select 'vacuum', date from t 
  where vacuum = 't' order by date desc limit 1
) union all (
  select 'wash', date from t 
  where wash = 't' order by date desc limit 1
)
```

To ensure blazing fast performance for this query, you need to create the following indexes:

```
create index ix1 on t (sweep, date);
create index ix2 on t (dust, date);
create index ix3 on t (vacuum, date);
create index ix4 on t (wash, date);
```

Comment: Thanks. The indexes is a great idea and something I often overlook.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a lateral join and aggregation:

```
select v.task, max(date)
from t cross join lateral
     (case when sweep then 'sweep'
           when dust then 'dust'
           when vacuum then 'vacuum'
           when wash then 'wash'
      end) v(task)
group by v.task;
```

Note:  This assumes -- consistent with your data -- that there is one task per row.  This is easily adjusted if your data is not representative.

If you want this per item:

```
select t.item, v.task, max(date)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (case when sweep then 'sweep'
                   when dust then 'dust'
                   when vacuum then 'vacuum'
                   when wash then 'wash'
              end)
     ) v(task)
group by t.item, v.task;
```

EDIT:

If you have multiple flags per row, then:

```
select v.task, max(date)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (case when sweep then 'sweep' end),
             (case when dust then 'dust' end),
             (case when vacuum then 'vacuum' end),
             (case when wash then 'wash' end)
     ) v(task)
where v.task is not null
group by v.task;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did have multiple tasks in rows 3 & 5, and have ended up with something like this which gives me one result row per item which will help in querying for datatables later.  I'm not too familiar with LATERAL so do you see where a LATERAL could improve this:

```SELECT t1.item, MAX(t1.date) AS sweep, MAX(t2.date) AS dust, MAX(t3.date) AS vacuum, MAX(t4.date) AS wash
FROM (SELECT * FROM task WHERE sweep) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT date FROM task WHERE dust) t2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT date FROM task WHERE vacuum) t3
CROSS JOIN (SELECT date FROM task WHERE wash) t4
GROUP BY t1.item
```

Comment: @AndrewT . . . I fixed the syntax error in the answer and added an edit for multiple flags.